# Two variables in a django url

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='child')
```

views.py

```
def category(request, parent, child):
    c = Category.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True)
    s = Category.objects.filter(parent__isnull=False)

    if child == False:
        p = Product.objects.filter(category__name__exact=parent)
        return render_to_response('all_products.html', {'current_category': get_object_or_404(Category, name=parent), 'c':c, 'p':p, 's':s })
    else:
        p = Product.objects.filter(category__name__exact=child)
        return render_to_response('all_products.html', {'current_category': get_object_or_404(Category, parent__name=parent, slug=child), 'c':c, 'p':p, 's':s })
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^products/(?P<parent>[-\w]+)/(?P<child>[-\w]+)/$', 'products.views.category'),
url(r'^products/(?P<parent>[-\w]+)/$', 'products.views.category', { 'child' : False }),
```

I'm building a view for a simple two level category app.  The above works I just don't think it's very clean, any tips for improving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequently I do the following:

models.py: Your "related_name" value is supposed to be plural.  "child" makes it hard to understand what is going on, while "child_set" makes it clear that there could be more than one.

```
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='child_set')
```

views.py: Make sure you only search the parent category for the child

```
def category(request, parent, child=None):
    parent = Category.objects.get(name=parent)
    if child:
        child = parent.child_set.get(name=child)

    return render_to_response('all_products.html', {
        'p': Product.objects.all(),
        'c': parent,
        's': child,
        'current_category': child or parent,
    })
```

urls.py: Nest your patterns to leverage the DRY principle

```
view_prefix = 'products.views'
url_patterns = patterns('',
    (r'^products/(?P<parent>[^/]+)/', include(patterns(view_prefix,
        url(r'^$', 'category'),
        url(r'^(?P<child>[^/]+)/$', 'category'),
    ))),
)
```